# How can I change the Guest account's background image?

Tags: macos, guest-account

When I login as guest, then change the background, logout, and log back in, the background is not saved. How can I choose which background the guest account will have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This article](http://www.michaelsmac.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=394) explains it very nice. Basically you are modifying a "User Template" file, which is used to create a fresh new user every time you log in as a Guest. If you're not quite sure on how to do it just ask for help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the instruction. Is there a way to only replace the guest's background? Where is it stored? Can't it be easily replaced like the DefaultDesktop.jpg of the login window?

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: Actually his link, which is the first link in his response, worked very well for me and was user friendly (as long as you are comfortable editing files with programing code. Which his/her link was very specific about. I'm not hacker, but I have experience and this worked perfectly.

Comment: The link is now dead... demonstrating the importance of the request above to give complete answers! The wayback machine has a [copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20131016173851/http://michaelsmac.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=394).